# Should I tell my prospective employer I’m going back to school ?

Tags: new-job, layoff

I was laid off 5 months back and I just got a job offer yesterday. It’s a contract position for 1 yr and the contract details have not yet been mailed to me. The problem is that I’m going back to school after 4 months to start my undergraduate degree and it’s full time studies for the program I’m taking. Should I accept the contract now and tell my manager after 3 months that I’m going to school and possibly convince him to let me work part time until summer? Or should I tell him now and face the possibility of losing the offer ?

Note: I already have a diploma and was working for two and a half years at another company before I decided to go back to university and finish my degree

Comment: How is the termination clause in the contract worded?  How much notice do you have to give and what's the penalty (if any) for early termination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Elysians answer (+1) correctly covers the morality of your question I'll take a different angle.  Possible benefits of telling this employer about your future plans are...

- The may be able to accommodate your three month contract easier than you think.
- They may be okay with you going back to school and keeping you on as a part-time developer, or keep you on in some kind of inactive status, in case they wish to employ you once your schooling is complete.  After all, if they decide they like you after three months, they'll want you as a permanent employee any way they can.
- Assuming the above is correct they may support you financially going back to school, although that's usually as a FTE and not as a contractor.
- They may counter with some benefits to you working for them for the year such that it would be better for you to delay schooling until the contract is complete, on terms favorable to you.

Answer (score 3):

> Or should I tell him now and face the possibility of losing the offer ?

This depends on your personal morals, basically. I would feel very bad accepting a 12 month contract **knowing** I was only going to complete 1/3 of it. I am unsure how/why you ended up interviewing for this type of job knowing you would be going back to school, so I am assuming something has changed in the process of your application.

You may not feel similarly about your situation. Or there may be financial pressures.

What I would do *personally* is talk with the manager and talk through the situation like: "Hey hiring manager, this is awkward but concurrent to this application process, I have applied to school and will be going to school fulltime on X. I would love to work fulltime until then and would be interested in part-time work of Y hours/week during the school year. Are there any sorts of arrangements that would work?"

That is because I value honesty to the point I would feel dishonest accepting a job with a specific timeframe attached I knew I could not, would not, and have no plans to complete.

> I just got a job offer yesterday

Read your offer very carefully if you do end up choosing to accept the offer knowing you plan on quitting to fully understand the contract you are entering into.

You will also likely burn bridges with this company if you accept a 12 month contract and then leave for school after 3 months.

Comment: Thank you , I personally like your advice. I don’t have the contract in hand yet but I will let the HR know once I get it